# I would like to use Flutter, but there is no needed package, just cocoapods

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, kotlin

I have a question for Flutter users.

I would like to implement my product by Flutter. And I have to use the vender package.
However, this vender doesn't have Flutter package, just iOS CocoaPods SDK and Android SDK.

What should I do below these choices.

#1. I gave up to implement by flutter. To use Swift and Android.
#2. To ask this vender to make the package for flutter.
#3. Other way to use iOS SDK and Android SDK on Flutter.

Please let me know your advice.

V/r,

Comment: Moreover, I'm beginner for Flutter. I think I don't have much information for Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could develop your own plugin, but the quickest route is to use [PlatformChannels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Install the native iOS and Android components as per normal then you can use platform channels from the dart side to interact with them. If the native components have UI then you will need to manage that on the native code side.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is still moving fairly fast.  You would be best served to keep a git checkout maintained.  Once you download the initial distro, and set the path correctly, you can keep it up to date with `flutter upgrade`.  Just a small matter of `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` and then adding `flutter/bin` (full path needed) to your executable path.

Edit: not clear to me whether the concern is installing flutter itself by a package (for which this is my answer), or installing some flutter plugin provided by a service vendor.  Hard to tell even on re-reading.